# Data is undefined in fetch post request

Tags: javascript, api, asynchronous, post

I am making a fetch api POST request to a url. When I print the data to my console, it says undefined. Here is my code:

```
function arCall(url = '', data = {}) {
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', 
    mode: 'cors', 
    cache: 'no-cache', 
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' +btoa('<my Username>:<my Password>'),
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data) 
  })
  .then((res) => console.log(res))
  .then(data => console.log(data))
} 

arCall('<my URL>', { id: 111 });
```

In the inspect tab on chrome, this is what the output looks like:

[image]

This is the Response object:

[image]

Could the reason for the undefined data be that I am getting a 403 forbidden error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: (And no, nothing to do with the status code of the response.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
>  .then((res) => console.log(res))
>  .then(data => console.log(data))
> ```

The value passed to a `then` callback is the resolved value of the promise returned from the previous step in the chain.

The return value of `console.log` is `undefined`.

Therefore `.then((res) => console.log(res))` returns a promise that resolves as `undefined`.

Therefore the value passed to `data` is `undefined`.

---

In the general case, you'll want to call one of the functions that processes the body of the response object and returns a promise that resolves as its value.

```
  .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        return res.text();
  })
  .then(data => console.log(data))
```

---

In this specific case, since you are getting a 403 Forbidden response, that's unlikely to be useful and you should change the request so you get a more useful response.